# Why 0 rules in Apriori algorithm in R

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I'm doing Association rule mining in R. This's the dataset I'm using [enter link description here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/akashdeepkuila/bakery).[image]

And here's my code.I can't understand why I'm getting 0 rules.

```
library(readr)
Bakery <- read_csv("Bakery.csv")
View(Bakery)
summary(Bakery)

library(arules)
rules  <- apriori(Bakery)
summary(rules)
```

Then I'm getting this output.Pls help.[image]

Comment: Please do not share code or data as images. Insert them as formatted plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the data frame into a transactions class to be used for `arules`. Try this:

```
Bakery_data <- as(split(Bakery[,"Items"], Bakery[,"TransactionNo"]), "transactions") 

rules  <- apriori(Bakery_data)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting this error sir  `>Error in asMethod(object) : can coerce list with atomic components only`